# Criar conteúdo exclusivo no WordPress (sem plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, condição

estou com um pouco de dificuldade para raciocinar uma lógica decente para um tema do wodpress apresentar conteúdo exclusivo.

A ideia é a seguinte: preciso enviar um email, que vai conter um parâmetro no link que vai habilitar a visualização do post.

Onde eu estou penando: se eu colocar apenas uma validação na single.php para verificar se o parametro existe, eu bloqueio o acesso do post para todos que não tem acesso.

Minha solução até agora: fiz uma gambs aqui para toda vez que um post for salvo marcando a opção de exclusivo, esse id vai para uma tabela no bd chamada posts exclusivos.

Alguém que já passou por tal dificuldade, pode me ajudar no raciocínio?

Valeu galera.

Answer (score 1):

Thierry, sua idéia de tratar o parametro na single está correto. Você pode usar o parametro para validar e quando não for válido, exibir um erro ou redirecionar para outra página. :)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! já consegui vencer essa questão! :D

Comment: Comenta sua solução aí! Sempre temos o que aprender uns com os outros!